# NameError: name '__' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys
print ('Welcome to FouuLs\' tax calculator!')

print ('To start, enter your marital status:')

M = input('(1) Single, (2) Married filing jointly or qualifying 
widow(er), (3) Married filing separately, or (4) Head of Household: ')

#Single
if M == "Single" or M == '1':
    T = int(input('Please insert your taxable income here:'))
    R = "tax rate"
if T>0 and T<9325:
        R = .10 * T
elif T>9326 and T<37950:
        R = .15 * T + 932.50
elif T>37951 and T<91900:
        R = .25 * T + 5226.25
elif T>919101 and T<191650:
        R = .28 * T + 18713.75
elif T>191651 and T<416700:
        R = .33 * T + 46643.75
elif T>416701 and T<418400:
        R = .35 * T + 120910.25
elif 418401<T:
        R = float(.396) * float(T) + 121505.25
else:
        print ('Error: Please type a valid numerical value for taxable 
income')

tax_owed = R
print ("You owe $ {}" .format(tax_owed))
sys.exit()

#Married Filing Jointly or Qualifying Widow
if M == "Married filing jointly or qualifying widower" or M == '2':
    T = int(input('Please insert your taxable income here:'))
    R = "tax rate"
if T>0 and T<18650:
        R = .10
elif T>18651 and T<75900:
        R = .15 * 1865
elif T>75901 and T<153100:
        R = .25 * 10452.50
elif T>153101 and T<233350:
        R = .28 * 29752.50
elif T>233351 and T<416700:
        R = .33 * 52222.50
elif T>416701 and T<470700:
        R = .35 * 112728
elif 470701<T:
        R = float(.396) * float(131628)
else:
        print("Error: Please type in a valid numerical value for 
taxable income")
tax_owed = R
print ("You owe $ {}" .format(tax_owed))
sys.exit()

#Married Filing Separately
if M == "Married filing separately" or M == '3':
    T = int(input('Please insert your taxable income here:'))
    R = "tax rate"
if T>0 and T<9325:
        R = .10
elif T>9326 and T<37950:
        R = .15 * 932.50
elif T>37951 and T<76550:
        R = .25 * 5226.25
elif T>76551 and T<116675:
        R = .28 * 14876.25
elif T>116676 and T<208350:
        R = .33 * 26111.25
elif T>208351 and T<235350:
        R = .35 * 56364
elif 235351<T:
        R = .396 * 65814
else:
        print("Error: Please type in a valid numerical value for 
taxable income")
tax_owed = R
print ("You owe $ {}" .format(tax_owed))
sys.exit()

#Head of Household
if M == "Head of Household" or M == '4':
    T = int(input('Please insert your taxable income here:'))
    R = "tax rate"
if T>0 and T<9325:
        R = .10
elif T>9326 and T<37950:
        R = .15 * 1335
elif T>37951 and T<91900:
        R = .25 * 6952.50
elif T>919101 and T<191650:
        R = .28 * 27052.50
elif T>191651 and T<416700:
        R = .33 * 49816.50
elif T>416701 and T<418400:
    R = .35 * 117202.50
elif T>418401:
        R = .396 * 126950
else:
        print("Error: Please enter a valid numerical value for taxable 
income")
tax_owed = R
print ("You owe $ {}" .format(tax_owed))
sys.exit
```

I'm new to programming, and I've been getting this error with my first project:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mattsetaro/Desktop/taxcalc2017.py", line 12, in <module>
if T>0 and T<9325:
NameError: name 'T' is not defined
```

I'm not getting the error for "single" or when M = 1, but when M > 1, I get this error. The script works completely for single as well, no errors whatsoever. Any help would be much appreciated, also if you have any suggestions on how to improve the code, fire away.

Comment: Your code is not indented properly.  Everything that's flush left is being executed unconditionally, but most of it is only meaningful for a particular marital status.  In Python, indentation is the *only* way of indicating the extent of an `if` statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should see the how if...elif...else construct works in python as shown [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/nested_if_statements_in_python.htm). And by indenting your code properly it is working fine as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
print ('Welcome to FouuLs\' tax calculator!')

print ('To start, enter your marital status:')

M = input('(1) Single, (2) Married filing jointly or qualifying \
widow(er), (3) Married filing separately, or (4) Head of Household: ')

#Single
if M == "Single" or M == '1':
    T = int(input('Please insert your taxable income here:'))
    R = "tax rate"
    if T>0 and T<9325:
        R = .10 * T
    elif T>9326 and T<37950:
        R = .15 * T + 932.50
    elif T>37951 and T<91900:
        R = .25 * T + 5226.25
    elif T>919101 and T<191650:
        R = .28 * T + 18713.75
    elif T>191651 and T<416700:
        R = .33 * T + 46643.75
    elif T>416701 and T<418400:
        R = .35 * T + 120910.25
    elif 418401<T:
        R = float(.396) * float(T) + 121505.25
    else:
        print ('Error: Please type a valid numerical value for taxable \
    income')

    tax_owed = R
    print ("You owe $ {}" .format(tax_owed))
    sys.exit()

#Married Filing Jointly or Qualifying Widow
if M == "Married filing jointly or qualifying widower" or M == '2':
    T = int(input('Please insert your taxable income here:'))
    R = "tax rate"
    if T>0 and T<18650:
        R = .10
    elif T>18651 and T<75900:
        R = .15 * 1865
    elif T>75901 and T<153100:
        R = .25 * 10452.50
    elif T>153101 and T<233350:
        R = .28 * 29752.50
    elif T>233351 and T<416700:
        R = .33 * 52222.50
    elif T>416701 and T<470700:
        R = .35 * 112728
    elif 470701<T:
        R = float(.396) * float(131628)
    else:
        print("Error: Please type in a valid numerical value for \
    taxable income")
    tax_owed = R
    print ("You owe $ {}" .format(tax_owed))
    sys.exit()

#Married Filing Separately
if M == "Married filing separately" or M == '3':
    T = int(input('Please insert your taxable income here:'))
    R = "tax rate"
    if T>0 and T<9325:
        R = .10
    elif T>9326 and T<37950:
        R = .15 * 932.50
    elif T>37951 and T<76550:
        R = .25 * 5226.25
    elif T>76551 and T<116675:
        R = .28 * 14876.25
    elif T>116676 and T<208350:
        R = .33 * 26111.25
    elif T>208351 and T<235350:
        R = .35 * 56364
    elif 235351<T:
        R = .396 * 65814
    else:
        print("Error: Please type in a valid numerical value for \
    taxable income")
    tax_owed = R
    print ("You owe $ {}" .format(tax_owed))
    sys.exit()

#Head of Household
if M == "Head of Household" or M == '4':
    T = int(input('Please insert your taxable income here:'))
    R = "tax rate"
    if T>0 and T<9325:
        R = .10
    elif T>9326 and T<37950:
        R = .15 * 1335
    elif T>37951 and T<91900:
        R = .25 * 6952.50
    elif T>919101 and T<191650:
        R = .28 * 27052.50
    elif T>191651 and T<416700:
        R = .33 * 49816.50
    elif T>416701 and T<418400:
        R = .35 * 117202.50
    elif T>418401:
        R = .396 * 126950
    else:
        print("Error: Please enter a valid numerical value for taxable \
    income")
    tax_owed = R
    print ("You owe $ {}" .format(tax_owed))
    sys.exit
```

Second thing to note is alway use backslash when you are writing long statements using print statement or within input() as I have used above.

Saving the file as fouuls_script and executing it with python gives output as shown below:

```
python fouuls_script.py 
Welcome to FouuLs' tax calculator!
To start, enter your marital status:
(1) Single, (2) Married filing jointly or qualifying widow(er), (3) Married filing separately, or (4) Head of Household: 4
Please insert your taxable income here:16300
You owe $ 200.25
```